# How can I sum a row where a letter corresponds to a value depending on the text in another cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am creating a document where some work can be tracked against a known score for a task. Currently I have 3 levels of difficulty for work, and each task has their own score against each difficulty.

Example:

Cell A1 = easy/medium/hard

Cell B1:J1, B2:J2, B3:J3 = various integers (1,2,3 etc.) - these are the weightings for each task. B1 range = easy, B2 range = medium etc.

Cell A2 = where I want the score to go

Cell B4:J4 = the letter "c" which is used to represent a complete task

Now I want cell A2 to update as I mark tasks with the letter "c" for complete. It should check what difficulty is in A1, and then select the correct task score from the correct range and add it to cell A2.

I don't know if I explained this well, but I would hope for some help!.

Comment: Some sample data with expected output would be better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SUMIFS with INDEX to pass the correct row:

```
=SUMIFS(INDEX(B1:J3,MATCH(A1,{"Easy","Medium","Hard"},0),0),B4:J4,"c")
```

[image]

Comment: This seems very close to what I was looking for! For more info:

The sum in A2 should read 6. As row B and E have c for medium (2+6). At the moment it's a total of the Easy, Medium & Hard rows (4+6+7)?

I will play around with this formula though so thank you.

Comment: Ignore me! I did not see the third c! Thank you for this!!!!